# Building URL from name

Tags: django, django-views

I've got a url of 'accounts:produce_setup' (i.e. namespace/app is 'accounts' and name of url is 'product_setup'). I'd like to build the full url associated with this view and pass it as context into a template.

How would I go about doing this? Would I use build_absolute_uri()?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to. You can simply use `{% url "accounts:product_setup" %}` in template. For more details check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url). And if you want to build the url is views(maybe for other reasons) you can use [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse).

Answer (score 1):

you should include your app in `project_name/urls.py` and bind your application to special URL pattern like this:

```
from account.urls import urlpatterns as account_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^account/', include(account_urlpatterns, namespace='account')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

and after this in your `account/urls.py` you can implement your urlpatterns and set your special name for each url like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import produce_setup_view

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^produce_setup/$', produce_setup_view, name='produce_setup')),
]
```

at the end now you can use them in your `template` and `views or any python file in your django project` like this:

`.py` in `django` project:

```
from django.urls import reverse

url_string = reverse('account:produce_setup')
print(url_string)

>>> '/account/produce_setup/'
```

in `template`:

```
<a href="{% url "accounts:product_setup" %}"></a>
```

Good Luck :)